# sql sessionState time out vs forms authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net

I would like to display the "Your session has expired" on logon page if session has been idle for given 5 minutes.

What should the time out value be for Sql Session State and Form Authentication Time Out:

> 1. same?
> 2. session state> form timeout
> 3. Form time out > session time.

ideally, if someone could explain the diff between above will be appreciated.

Currently, my code looks like below and Session["SessionID"] is not Null even after Login redirection for idle of 5 minute:

```
On Session_Start()
 Session["SessionID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

On LogOn.cshtml:

```
 @{
        string sessionExpiredMsg = string.Empty;

        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx.Session["SessionID"] == null)
        {
            sessionExpiredMsg = "Your session has expired. Please re-login again.";
        }
    }
@
```

On web.config:

```
<sessionState
timeout=5....

<authentication mode="forms"
 timeout=5....
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Session state timeout means that your asp.net session will expire in x minutes. It doesn't mean that your're not authenticated anymore.
- Forms timeout means that after x minutes, you'll be prompted to log in again(not authenticated anymore).

It's not a problem if your sessionstate timeout lasts longer that your forms timeout because once you'll log in again you will retrieve the last one if not expired.

Comment: Thanks lnu, i've updated my question with codes which is not working.

Comment: ctx.Session["SessionID"] still contains the value even after login redirection. Not sure why.

Comment: have you seen this:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/06/21/detecting-session-timeout-in-asp-net-2-0-web-applications.aspx

Comment: yep that is what I used, and doesn't work. Session is not null even redirection to Login page

Comment: Try to put 10 minutes for your forms timeout and 1 minute for your session. I've done the same as you and my session is empty( and Session.IsNew==true) after 1 minute. But it keeps the same sessionid.